# Have non-boolean result in Case When Function

Tags: sql, case-when

I am trying to create a query that will break results into separate columns. The best formula that I can find is the Case When function, but it says the Then part of the equation must be Boolean (or a true/false result). Is there a way for the Then to calculate a number 3-1 for example?

```
Case
when
    DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) > 0 
    AND DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) < 30 
then
(T0.[DocTotal] - T0.[PaidToDate]) 
else
    ' ' 
end
as "Greater than 1", 
Case
when
    DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) > 30 
    AND DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) < 60 
then
(T0.[DocTotal] - T0.[PaidToDate]) 
else
    ' ' 
end
as "Greater than 30"
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Then shouldn't necessarily be a boolean, but I think that your issue is that what you have in THEN and ELSE are not same types (ie. THEN is decimal, and ELSE is varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use sql server then your code snip will be like below.
you have to keep same data type on after `then` and `else` as you used string type after using else so you have to convert it on later `then`

```
Case
when
    DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) > 0 
    AND DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) < 30 
then
( convert(varchar(255), T0.[DocTotal] - T0.[PaidToDate]))
else
    ' ' 
end
as Greater_than_1, 
Case
when
    DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) > 30 
    AND DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) < 60 
then
(convert(varchar(255), T0.[DocTotal] - T0.[PaidToDate])) 
else
    ' ' 
end
as Greater_than_30
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with type compatibility.  I would recommend that you simply use `NULL` for no match:

```
(case when DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) > 0 AND DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) < 30 
      then (T0.[DocTotal] - T0.[PaidToDate]) 

 end) as Greater_than_1, 
(case when DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) > 30  and DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) < 60 
      then (T0.[DocTotal] - T0.[PaidToDate]) 
 end) as Greater_than_30
```

I would also guess that you intend `<= 30` for the first condition.

Answer (score 0):

Found that i needed to cast the equation as an integer as below.

```
Case when 
    DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) > 0 
    AND DATEDIFF(day, T0.[DocDueDate], getdate()) <30 
then 
    cast( (T0.[DocTotal]-T0.[PaidToDate]) as varchar(12) ) 
else 
    ' ' 
end as "Greater than 1"
```

Comment: When inserting the code, you can add formatting using the "{ }" button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do this with a variety of methods. TSET is just generating dates from June 1 to today for the test.

```
WITH tset(td)
     AS (
     SELECT CAST('2018-08-01' AS DATE) AS td
     UNION ALL
     SELECT DATEADD(d, -1, td)
     FROM   tset
     WHERE  td > CAST('2018-06-01' AS DATE))
     -- Actual examples start here
     SELECT td
          -- Diff is just showing the difference in days so you can see the group assignements
          , DATEDIFF(d, td, GETDATE()) AS diff
          -- This column groups into < 30, 31-60, and > 60
          , CASE
                WHEN DATEDIFF(d, td, GETDATE()) < 30 THEN 1 ELSE CASE
                                                                     WHEN DATEDIFF(d, td, GETDATE()) < 60 THEN 2 ELSE 3
                                                                 END
            END three_sets
          -- this example will group  into any number of 30 day sets.
          , cast ( DATEDIFF(d, td, GETDATE()) as int) / 30 any_number_of_sets
     FROM   tset
     ORDER BY td;
```

Some sample Results:

```
td        diff  three_sets  any_number_of_sets
2018-06-01  66  3   2
2018-06-02  65  3   2
2018-06-03  64  3   2
. . .

2018-06-12  55  2   1
2018-06-13  54  2   1
2018-06-14  53  2   1
. . .
2018-07-09  28  1   0
2018-07-10  27  1   0
2018-07-11  26  1   0
```